# Find all homomorphisms $\phi: \Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/15\Bbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism, ring-homomorphism

Note that the question is asked in exercises for rings yet the question just mentions homomorphisms and doesn't specify group or ring. I am guessing this is because it is both a group and ring homomorphism?

I was trying to follow (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1869580)'s answer but it was kind of hard because I didn't understand how $\left \langle 1\;\; (mod\;\;4) \right \rangle= \Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$. Isn't it $\left \langle 1+4\Bbb{Z} \right \rangle =\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$?

By using Lagrange's theorem and properties of homomorphisms, I found that |$\phi(1 + 6\Bbb{Z})|=\left \{ 1,3 \right \}$. The problem for me is finding the set $\phi(1+6\Bbb{Z})$ since I don't know how to determine individual orders of the elements in $\Bbb{Z}/15\Bbb{Z}=\left \{15\Bbb{Z},...,14+15\Bbb{Z}  \right \}$.

Am I doing anything wrong and is my notation awkward?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at group homomorphisms first.

If $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}f\colon\Z/6\Z\to\Z/15\Z$ is given, then it is determined by $f(1+6\Z)=a+15\Z$ and it must be
$$
6(a+15\Z)=0+15\Z
$$
that is, $6a\equiv0\pmod{15}$ that immediately becomes $a\equiv0\pmod{5}$. So the only possibilities for $a$ are $0$, $5$ and $10$.

Each of these possibilities gives indeed a homomorphism, as you can check.

Now, a ring homomorphism is also a group homomorphism. If your definition of ring homomorphism requires preserving the identity, none of those satisfies it.

Suppose we have $f(1+6\Z)=5+15\Z$. Then $f(2+6\Z)=10+15\Z$ and $f(4+6\Z)=5+15\Z$. What's $(10+15\Z)^2$?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I now understand where to get $0,5,10$! There are a total of $2$ homomorphisms since $0^{2}\equiv 0$, $5^{2}\equiv 10$, and $10^{2}\equiv 10$ (mod $15$) My new problem is...how to write out these two homomorphisms?

Comment: @numericalorange For a ring homomorphism, $f(4)=f(2)f(2)$, so $f(1)=5$ is impossible. Is $f(1)=10$ possible?

Comment: Would $f(1)=10$ and $f(1)=0$ be possible?

Comment: @numericalorange Try your hand with the first (no); for the latter, yes: you map everything to $0$.